# Granular Audio Controls like a PC

Tags: audio

Is there a way to:

1. Allow for an indefinite number of apps to play audio at the same time. Or in other words, to not allow any app to stop the audio playback of another (other than calls).
2. If 1. is possible, adjust the volume each app on a per app basis

thanks